# Use where condition in linq's include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, exception

How can I use where condition in include?
ProgressItems is ICollection<> object. I want to get whole Goal object with filtered items. How can I resolve it?

```
        return _dbContext.Goals
            .Include(p => p.GoalExpectation)
            .Include(p => p.ProgressItems.Where(r => r.Value > 100))
            .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
```

I get such exception

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties. Parameter name: path

Comment: Linq To SQL and Entity Framework does not support filtered includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include Statement expects a navigation property (as the error says). Purely syntactically it seems correct what you do, but it appears to be sementically wrong, because `Where` does not return a navigation property.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you'd have to limit it by using a query that can get the included items with the filter and assign that to your Goal object.